# Why was my question migrated?

Tags: discussion

So I asked the question https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161276/how-would-even-more-internet-regulation-hinder-terrorism on here and then it got migrated over to Security.SE, where I then flagged it for moderator intervention and they deemed it off-topic for there too.

So my question is how is this question off-topic for Politics.SE and migrated as such?

I feel it aligns with policy from the current perspective of the government (which is on-topic here and it had no VTCs before mod intervention), which in turn is a reaction to the current events that have occurred in both London and Manchester, Theresa May feels regulating the internet will help combat terrorism (or extremism) and isn't about the technological viewpoint of such processes and the comments on that question (in it's current form) back up my query.

<sup>**Note**: This is more aimed at Phillip than anyone else.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I felt that this was a question which can be much better answered by people who are experts on cryptography and censorship technology than by people who are experts on politics.

In order to tell if the kind of internet regulation proposed by May would be effective, you would need to tell if it is technically feasible and technically effective. That's nothing a politician can tell you. A security professional can.

Anyway, I reopened [the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19572/how-would-even-more-internet-regulation-hinder-terrorism?noredirect=1) on Politics.SE. But I would recommend to read [the answers the question received from the Security.SE community](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/161276/how-would-even-more-internet-regulation-hinder-terrorism?noredirect=1) before it was closed, because they are very insightful.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, I've certainly read them and they were indeed insightful. I just felt @Carpetsmoker answered my question in the context I asked.

Comment: But ... but ... this takes away all my new reputation and shiny badges on security.SE :-( :-(